# Powershell timeout service

Tags: powershell, service, timeout

I am trying to start a service in Powershell.  If the service does not start within a specified time limit, the attempt to start should be killed, otherwise it should carry on as usual.  How do I incorporate a timeout?

Comment: I googled "Powershell timeout starting service" and the first hit has an answer for you: http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/5243/Default.aspx

Comment: The code posted did not work properly, which was the problem when we originally stumbled upon that link, but we were able to fix it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implementing a timeout is a really simple thing to do using background jobs:

```
$timeout = [Timespan]"0:0:15"
$start = Get-Date
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBLock { Import-Module MyModule; Invoke-MyCommand}
do {
    if ($j.JobState -ne 'Running') { break} 
    $j | Receive-Job
} while (((Get-Date) - $start) -le $timeout)
```

This block of code will timeout after 15 seconds, but it should get you started.  Basically:
 - Track the time
 - Start a job
 - Wait for it to be no longer running (it could have failed, so don't just wait for completed)
 - Receive Results while you wait
 - Timeout if you've been waiting too long

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Is there a way to use milliseconds?  When I tried using "0:0:0:50" and "0:0:.5" it did not work properly.

Comment: Yes, you can use milliseconds with "0:0:0.5" (you were really close, and it's annoyingly picky).  You can also use [Timespan]::FromMilliseconds

Comment: It's `$j.State` instead of `$j.JobState` in v2.