# PowerShell Start-Service Timeout

Tags: powershell, timeout, stopwatch, start-process

#### Problem

I have been working on a timeout feature for the `Start-Services` feature of my application and have stumbled upon some setbacks in which the timeout doesn't work properly or fails to display properly.

My two constants are set as such:

```
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $SecondsToWait
$elapsedTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

The rest of my code has changed multiple time to try and achieve my goal. I have tried all of the following with little or no success. Each attempt will have a brief description:

In this instance, I attempted to create a new job, put the action inside of a Do While loop and Exit said loop if Elapsed Time = Timeout time or Job State is 'Running'. Unfortunately, this breaks during the while loop.

```
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue }

Do {
    If ($j.State -eq "Running") { break }
    $j | Receive-Job
} While ($elapsedTime -le $timeout)
```

I attempted the Do While loop in a different format, but still had issues getting it to work as it hits an infinite loop at the `Start-Service` line when it runs into a service it cannot start automatically.

```
Do {
    $counter++
    Start-Sleep 1
    Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

    # this line is just a custom function that gets the status of the service and checks a number of times based on the 'SecondsToWait' Parameter. 
    Wait-ServiceState -ServiceName $ServiceName -ServiceState "Running" -SecondsToWait 1
} While ($elapsedTime -le $timeout)
```

This too breaks at the Start-Service Cmdlet for a similar reason as the above instance

```
Do {
    $counter++
    Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
} While ($elapsedTime -eq $timeout)
```

I also tried using `Write-Progress` instead as a more dymanic variant... but that didn't do much in terms of initializing the `Start-Services` argument.

I have tried reading through several posts as well in hopes of finding alternative ways to do this, but even those variations failed... And as much as I liked the way `Write-Progress` worked... I couldn't understand how to clear it from the screen (without clearing the entire cmd screen) or how to control where it appears on the cmd window. Anyways, you can find those alternative resourses below:

[Powershell timeout service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566824/powershell-timeout-service-building)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1

[Powershell Start Process, Wait with Timeout, Kill and Get Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933527/powershell-start-process-wait-with-timeout-kill-and-get-exit-code)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-5.1

#### Question

Does anyone know how to resolve the issues with my code that would help me not only timeout the `Start-Process`, but to display the elapsed time properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer. You are using $elapsedTime wrong. $elapsedTime is your stopwatch. You cannot check it against your timeout directly. You need to check $elapsedTime.Elapsed (that is also the property to use to display your elapsed time.)

Answer (score 2):

You created a stopwatch called `$elapsedTime`

```
$elapsedTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

That is kind of confusing because the name you chose is not what it seems. 
Therefore, when you want to compare against your timeout, $elapsedTime is not the elapsed time represented as a timespan, as you might think quickly reading variable name, it is your Stopwatch object.

Therefore, your

```
 While ($elapsedTime -le $timeout)
```

should in fact be

```
While ($elapsedTime.Elapsed -le $timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I had just misunderstood how to utilize that. This has helped a great deal